# How to find wrong dates in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

I want all the records with the wrong date from my data base. There are some records dated like `0645-14-10`. Please note the data type of the column is VARCHAR.

I have tried with this query :

```
SELECT * from LTRECT_JOURNALS_T 
where DATE_PART (YEAR,CREATE_DATE like '06%')
```

So how I can I find these kind of records?

Comment: LIKE returns boolean TRUE/FALSE. Does DATE_PART want that as second argument? Has CREATE_DATE a character data type?

Comment: What's the data type of this column? What's the expected date format, if it's `(var)char` data type? Why is it wrong, if the data type is `date`?

Comment: the date type of the column is VARCHAR.

Comment: @APC OK. Actually i am new here so next time i will not.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein. the data type of the column is VARCHAR.

Comment: @SanaullahStanikzai Why is this date `0645-14-10` wrong? Is this because of expected `YYYY-MM-DD` format, and `YYYY-DD-MM` in fact?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein we don't have any data before 2003. i don't know from where this date came.

Comment: @SanaullahStanikzai You don't answer to my questions unfortunately. Once again, what's the full technical description of a "wrong" date (this may be wrong format, too early date, etc.) in this column, if you still need a solution?

Comment: @MarkBarinstein This is too early date in this column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should cast the string representation of date first and not compare it to a date constant. This doesn't work in Db2, If you uncomment the commented out line and comment out the last one.

```
WITH LTRECT_JOURNALS_T (CREATE_DATE) AS 
(
VALUES '0645-14-10', '2003-14-10', '2002-14-10'
)  
SELECT *
FROM LTRECT_JOURNALS_T 
WHERE 
--CREATE_DATE < date('2003-01-01')
YEAR(TO_DATE(CREATE_DATE, 'YYYY-DD-MM')) < 2003
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a simple test to find dates in the seventh century CE:

```
SELECT * from LTRECT_JOURNALS_T 
where CREATE_DATE < date '0700-01-01'
/
```

Comment: OK, but not all the records has less then seventh century date, maybe some records  will have different values.

Comment: Unfortunately we can only answer the question you ask. If you want to search for a range of "wrong" dates your question needs to include that information, in this case specifying the criteria for determining wrongness.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UDF function that will attempt to convert the string to a date, but capture the error generated if it fails and return false instead.

E.g.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION IS_DATE(i VARCHAR(64)) RETURNS INTEGER
    CONTAINS SQL 
    ALLOW PARALLEL
    NO EXTERNAL ACTION
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN 
  DECLARE NOT_VALID CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '22007';
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR NOT_VALID RETURN 0;

  RETURN CASE WHEN CAST(i AS DATE) IS NOT NULL THEN 1 END;
END
```

Change the statement terminator when creating the above. E.g. use `@` not `;`

On Db2 11.1 or lower, remove the `ALLOW PARALLEL` line from the above SQL

Then, e.g.

```
VALUES IS_DATE('0645-14-10')
```

will return 0, but

```
VALUES IS_DATE('0645-12-10')
```

will return 1